# Enterprise Architect - Undo checkout branch

Tags: enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect you can checkout a single package  or checkout a branch (includes all sub packages)

EA then provides the ability to undo a checkout but it doesn't seem to provide the ability to undo the checkout of a branch.  This means that you have to undo each package individually (which can be time consuming)

Does anyone know if the "undo-ing" of a branch can be achieved any other way?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The t_package.packageFlags keep the data whether the package is checked-out.
In case the package is checked-out, there is something like `"CheckedOutTo=<username>;"` in the package flags.

The way is that:
1. Delete this part from the package flags. The pacakge icon will return to the regular state.
2. To release the assocaited locked file from the version control working copy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Right click the package, Package control - >undo checkcout. Discard the changes..

Comment: That is for a single package, not for a branch as was asked.